# Do I need constructor body in Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I couldn't find a difference between:

```
constructor (private router: Router) { }
```

and

```
router: Router;    

constructor (private _router: Router) {
       this.router = _router
}
```

Variable `router` is available in the whole class and it contains the same data. So what's the difference between first and the second syntax?

Comment: 1st approach just shorthand syntax where you don't need to write boilerplate code,2nd one is just longer version of it.

Comment: No, by default, it's public. The second one actually defines two fields referencing the same object. One, `router`, is public, and the other one, `_router`, is private. Just use the first snippet. Everything is nicely explained in the official documentation. Why don't you read it? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Comment: @JBNizet when is the ninja squad book update for RC5 ?

Comment: @Ced Now. The email is coming, AFAIK, but the book is now up-to-date with RC5: NgModule, new forms api and everything: https://books.ninja-squad.com/angular2/changelog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically this:

```
constructor (private router: Router) { }
```

is short form of this:

```
private router: Router;    

constructor (_router: Router) {
    this.router = _router
}
```

Personally I use first format in all projects because it makes files shorter, and it is easier to read.

If your question about block inside of constructor, answer is - no. If you are using short form like I showed before, there no need to put anything in constructor. All needed init stuff you can put in `ngOnInit` function.

Short example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-cmp',
  template: `<p>my-component</p>`
})
class MyComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private myService: MyService
) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit');
  }
}
```

Comment: it's a pity that ` { }` can't be omitted